# System.OutOfMemoryException when loading multiple large images from disk

Tags: c#, .net, image, system.drawing

I try to load images from disk (sizes of 30 to 50 MB each) in a list as follows

```
    var images = new List<Image>();
    foreach (var imgPath in paths)
    {
        var img = Image.FromFile(imgPath);
        images.Add(img);
    }
```

The problem is that after the first or second image I get a

> System.OutOfMemoryException

...my guess is that the images are too large. I know that a good practice would be to process the images one by one, but I can't since I need all of them to be merged into a single one (like a collage) and I can't use thumbnails because I need to respect the original sizes.

I tried to change the `maxRequestLength` to `"10000000"`but it was useless.

Since I can't reach the image processing step I don't think that I have a problem with not disposing objects, at least not yet.

Is there a way to increase the memory available to work with, or something like that?

P.S. I use JPG format for images.

Comment: Are you sure it's after _"the first or second image"_?  _"30 to 50 MB each"_ - is tiny.  Looking at Google Chome right now as I type this it is using **129 MB** for comparison. Have you tried running the memory leak tools in VS?

Comment: What has `maxRequestLength` to do with _"load images from disk"_?

Comment: There are too many variables at play to easily help you, such as hardware configuration, OS, type of application, application configuration. Obviously you need to increase the memory available to your application, but it's very difficult to say how to accomplish that.

Comment: I haven't tried running the memory leak tools but I watched the memory usage for the app in Task Manager, when it crashed it was at 595 MB (base app and 4 photos loaded).

Comment: The increase of `maxRequestLength` was something that I found in another post.. I had to try that too.

Comment: From the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4sahykhd(v=vs.110).aspx), OutOfMemoryException can be thrown by Image.FromFile if _The file does not have a valid image format._ -or- _GDI+ does not support the pixel format of the file_. Check the message of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using:

```
Image.FromFile(path);
```

It's slow and will bloat your process
Instead:

```
var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var photo = Image.FromStream(fs, true, false);
```

Don't forget to dispose ;-)

Basically instead of bringing all that data into memory in one go and killing your app and all your loved ones. You operate the image as if it was a stream of data.

**Edit**

In either case I don't recommend editing all the images at once.
You'll probably get a OutOfMemoryException either way.

If possible work with two images at the time, once you're done, dispose them and move to the next set until your final image is complete.